# Find My 'Play Sound' notifications history

Tags: icloud, find-my

Someone **who's member of our iCloud family** was in a funny mood and played with us by notifying some of our devices using the *Play Sound* feature in *Find My* app.

An email is sent telling that an alert has sounded on the device with hour and date but containing no other detail — so we wonder out of curiosity if we could **find some sort of logs listing who could have triggered those alerts** ?

I can't find any information for this precise case, it always falls on iCloud accounts help or Find My features (*We found out who it was after few minutes but couldn't tell at the time of the alerts ringing*).

Comment: Just to mention, I don't really except an answer other than "No, we can't", that's pure curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an iCloud Family plan setup. Most of the devices are associated with my account, except for the kids and wife who all have their own iPhone or iPad. As a test, I just signed into my kids iCloud account. I was able to "Find My" iPhone that's next to me from my kid's account. So I guess there isn't a real way to see who did it, as nothing really told me which account sent the request.

If you think it's a child that is doing it, remove the app from their device, or use a configuration file to restrict the app from the device.

Good luck!